# How to create column inside a column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Following is the code used to create a DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
cols = ['Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3']
data = [['Row 1', '1.0', '{"tag1" : {0: \" \", 1: \" \"}, "tag2": {2: \" \", 3: \" \"}}'], ['Row 2', '2.0', '{"tag1" : {0: \" \", 1: \" \"}, "tag2": {2: \" \", 3: \" \"}}']]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols, data = data)
```

Below is the output of the DataFrame `df`

```
   Col 1 Col 2                                                  Col 3
0  Row 1   1.0  {"tag1" : {0: " ", 1: " "}, "tag2": {2: " ", 3: " "}}
1  Row 2   2.0  {"tag1" : {0: " ", 1: " "}, "tag2": {2: " ", 3: " "}}
```

How can I convert the above DataFrame into any of the tabular format as shown below?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, output the expected dataframe to get better help.

Comment: can you tell me the output of `type(df.loc[0,'Col 3'])` in your dataframe

Comment: @AnuragDabas <class 'str'>

Answer (score 0):

You can create each column using `eval` to convert the `string` into a `dictionary` and then accessing the required value, for example for the `col 0`:

```
df[0] = df['Col 3'].apply(lambda x: eval(x)['tag1'][0])
```